# Google Managed SSL certificate not working

Tags: ssl, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

So I hosted my website on GCP, and I'm using the App Engine.
I'm trying to get my website an SSL certificate.
So, I added a custom domain, completed the verification steps, added the DNS records but I still get this error message:

`DNS records could not be found. certificate activation will retry automatically.`

But, as you can see in this picture:

[image: Entered Dns Details]

[image: Second DNS]

[image: NotWorking]
I did enter them, but it's not working.
Note, for the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), it does work.

Comment: when you enter your custom domain naked url (example.com), does it load your GAE App?

Comment: It will be very easy to tell you what is wrong if you do not hide the domain name.

Comment: How long did you wait?

Comment: About a week... and yes, it does load, and I hide it because I don'y want people to somehow hack my website by knowing it uses http or something

Comment: I have had this experience two or three times before and it always got resolved when I removed the mapping for whatever subdomain wasn't working and added it again after some interval.